# Redirect URI not passing variable

Tags: php, oauth, instagram

I currently have a login REDIRECT URI setup with Instagram API (php) and it is working fine, meaning it logs me in and gets the relevant information. I am attempting to pass a URL variable that but the URL variable is not passed along through the oauth link.

This is the link that authenticates (with identifiable information removed)

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=REMOVED&redirect_uri=success.php?scope=basic&response_type=code&studyid=150

In success.php, I attempt to get the URL variable 'studyid'

```
$studyid = $_GET['studyid'];
```

The url however turns to this:

```
success.php?code=REMOVED
```

where REMOVED is some number. The important thing here is that the studyid variable disappears from the URL and so I can no longer retrieve it using GET. Does anyone know what happens between the first url (https://api.instagram.com/oauth...) and the second url (success.php?code=) where the studyid variable disappears? How can I pass this variable along?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
Please explain!!
on which page do u exactly want to go
if you want to go success.php then mention success.php in action field and used get method